# CSS justify-content in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: html, css, flexbox, jupyter-notebook

In jupyter notebook I write HTML code like this one:

```
<div style="display: flex;justify-content: center;border-color: coral;border-style:solid;">
   <div style="border-style:solid;">test</div>
   <div style="border-style:solid;">test2</div>
</div>
```

[This is what I get - justify-content: center seemingly does nothing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1otu3.png)

[This is what I want to get - each box aligned to center](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flexbox_justify-content_center)

What am I missing?

Comment: Your code should work as you want. Check the dev tools to see if there's an issue?

Comment: justify-content: center is missing when I check code with dev tools. I'm using Chrome 63.0.3239.84 64 bit. This may be an issue of jupyter notebook.

Comment: @holi1234 I think jupyter sanitizes these extra flexbox attributes and removes them. display:flex still works, but nothing else it seems.